# Load a Django template from a different app

Tags: python, django, django-templates

*Django 1.9*

How can I load "control/templates/control/emails/fuselage_job_complete" template from "fuselage/views.py"?

I want to use this template for [django-emailit](https://github.com/divio/django-emailit/).

I tried to call it like this:

`emailit.api.send_mail([task.user.email], {'task': task}, 'emails/fuselage_job_complete')`

I got the `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist` error.

Also tried this:

`emailit.api.send_mail([task.user.email], {'task': task}, 'control/emails/fuselage_job_complete')`

I got `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'site' takes at least one argument (path to a view)`.

My project structure:

```
web/
├── control
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── handlers.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── management
│   │   ├── commands
│   │   │   ├── create_researcher.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── search_alerts.py
│   │   │   ├── sync_omop_tree.py
│   │   │   └── sync_users.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── managers.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── signals.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── control
│   │       ├── emails
│   │       │   ├── fuselage_job_complete.body.html
│   │       │   ├── fuselage_job_complete.body.txt
│   │       │   ├── fuselage_job_complete.subject.txt
│   │       ├── json
│   │       │   ├── jsontree.json
│   │       │   └── omoptree.json
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── controltags.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── user.py
│   ├── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── images
│   ├── js
│   └── resources
├── templates
│   ├── emailit
│   │   └── base_email.body.txt
│   └── registration
├── fuselage
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── img
│   │   │   ├── loading.gif
│   │   │   └── loading-sm.gif
│   │   └── fuselage
│   │       ├── css
│   │       └── js
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── fuselage
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
└── rocket
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings
    │   ├── base.py
    │   ├── dev.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── local.py
    │   ├── production.py
    │   ├── test.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── wsgi.py
```

My template settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {   
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'absolute.context_processors.absolute',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: my opinion you asking "how to serve two template" ? Quick answer can't ! But can merge...

Comment: @dsgdfg how to do this merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in this way `emailit.api.send_mail([task.user.email], {'task': task}, 'control/emails/fuselage_job_complete')`, the settings are correct. The email templates had wrong syntax.